# Amplifier + Speakers setup

Tags: speakers, amplifier, setup, power

I have a noob question about an amp/speaker setup that I would like to buy.

I currently have a [Behringer EUROPOWER EP2000](http://www.behringer.com/EN/Products/EP2000.aspx) amplifier with two passive [Behringer EUROLIVE B212XL](http://www.behringer.com/EN/Products/B212XL.aspx) speakers. The amplifier can output 2000W of power, and the speakers can handle 200W continuous with a 800W peak.

I feel like I am not getting the most out of my amplifier, so I was thinking to upgrade to two [Behringer EUROLIVE VP2520](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0029RRGRC) speakers that can handle 500W continuous with a 2000W peak power.

Because the amplifier maximum power is 2000W, and I want two speakers, it can dedicate 1000W to each speaker. I may be wrong, but I understand that the 2000W peak power advertised is not something the speaker can sustain for a long period of time. Because the continuous power is 500W, my reasoning is that the amp with a 2000W output should be able to power both speakers at a reasonable level (around 500W each).

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in assuming that the speakers can only withstand the peak power for very short periods of time.

The VP2520 is a 4 Ω speaker. Looking at the technical specs of the amp, it seems the continous power per channel for a 4 Ω load is only 500 W (rms). The peak power is 750 W per channel. In other words, the VP2520 appears to be a perfect match for your amp!

Comment: As a general long life rule I usually like having the amps able to overpower speakers. It's like having a car that can go 150mph. It's not good to run it at that level for everyday use. But it will do really well at 75mph. An amp running at it's maximum capacity is much more likely to die or when it clips or overloads is more likely to blow the speakers. I'm not saying your particular advice is bad and that combo seems like it will work. I would however add that it's a good idea to keep in mind when matching up speakers and amps with their normal use.